flutter how can create the common textformfield to validate different input text(Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey.)
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:test/config/app_theme.dart';

class LoginInfoFormField extends StatelessWidget {
  const LoginInfoFormField(
      {required this.controller,
      required this.hintText,
      required this.labelText,
      this.validator,
      this.onChanged,
      this.inputFormatters,
      this.focusNode,
      this.enableSuggestions = true,
      this.autocorrect = true,
      this.obscureText = false,
      this.suffixIcon,
      super.key});
  final TextEditingController? controller;
  final String? Function(String?)? validator;
  final void Function(String)? onChanged;
  final List<TextInputFormatter>? inputFormatters;
  final FocusNode? focusNode;
  final String labelText;
  final String hintText;
  final bool enableSuggestions;
  final bool autocorrect;
  final bool obscureText;
  final Widget? suffixIcon;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Key: ${key.toString()}');
    return Theme(
      data: ThemeData(),
      child: TextFormField(
        key: key,
        controller: controller,
        focusNode: focusNode,
        obscureText: obscureText,
        validator: validator,
        onChanged: onChanged,
        enableSuggestions: enableSuggestions,
        autocorrect: autocorrect,
        inputFormatters: inputFormatters,
        style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondaryContainer),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: AppTheme.grayColor)),
            labelText: tr(labelText),
            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: context.locale == const Locale('my', 'MM') ? 13 : 16,
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondaryContainer),
            hintText: tr(hintText),
            hintStyle: TextStyle(
              fontSize: context.locale == const Locale('my', 'MM') ? 15 : 16,
            ),
            suffixIcon: suffixIcon),
      ),
    );
  }
}


import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:test/widgets/formfield/login_info_form_field.dart';

class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  const Login({super.key});

  @override
  State<Login> createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  
  final GlobalKey<FormFieldState> _userNameKey = GlobalKey<FormFieldState>();
  final GlobalKey<FormFieldState> _emailKey = GlobalKey<FormFieldState>();


  TextEditingController userNameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Column(
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(32, 0, 32, 10),
                                child: LoginInfoFormField(
                                 key: _userNameKey,
                                  controller: userNameController,
                                  validator: (value) {
                                    if ((value!).trim().isEmpty) {
                                      return tr('userNameRequired');
                                    }
                                    return null;
                                  },
                                  onChanged: (val) =>
                                      _userNameKey.currentState!.validate(),
                                  labelText: 'UserName',
                                  hintText: 'UserName',
                                ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                            32, 0, 32, 10),
                                  child: LoginInfoFormField(
                                    key: _emailKey,
                                    validator: (value) {
                                      if ((value!).trim().isEmpty) {
                                        return tr('emailIsRequired');
                                      }
                                      return null;
                                    },
                                    onChanged: (val) {
                                      _emailKey.currentState!.validate();
                                    },
                                    controller: emailController,
                                    inputFormatters: [
                                      FilteringTextInputFormatter
                                          .singleLineFormatter
                                    ],
                                    labelText: 'EnterYourEmail',
                                    hintText: 'EnterYourEmail',
                                  ),
                              )
                          ]
                        );
  }
}

I am facing the error and don't work validation.

Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey.
The key [LabeledGlobalKey<FormFieldState<dynamic>>#c646e] was used by multiple widgets. The parents of those widgets were: - DefaultSelectionStyle - _FormScope A GlobalKey can only be specified on one widget at a time in the widget tree.


remove GlobalKeys and use
autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
in TextFormField you don't have to use GlobalKeys for validate when value has been change
